# how do i find the angle in this trigonometry problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How do I find the ∠FAB?(knowing that the segment EF is the height of the triangle AFD)
[image]

I tried several attempts to resolve it but none of them were succesful.I managed to find the angles ACB(=51,39) and CAB(=38,68) but i didn't know what to do with that information.I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $FE^2 = AE\cdot ED=48\cdot 12 \implies FE = 24$. Thus,

$$\angle ? = \angle BAC - \angle FAR= \sin^{-1} \frac{BC}{AC} 
- \tan^{-1} \frac{FE}{AE} = \sin^{-1} \frac{5}{8}
- \tan^{-1} \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: what is the propriety of a triangle that makes the above relationship with FE and AE x ED true?

Comment: @0_0 - from similar triangles AFE and DFE

Answer (score 1):

Triangles $DFE$ and $DAF$ are similar. Then $$\frac{DE}{FD}=\frac{FD}{AD}\\\frac{12}{FD}=\frac{FD}{12+48}$$
From here you can get $FD$, then get $\angle DAF$ from the $DAF$ triangle.

Comment: how do you get FD with this formula?

Comment: $FD^2=12\cdot60$.